# Python: Naming conventions for modules & variables when they could conflict

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I generally try to follow the common Python style guides ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008), [Code Like a Pythonista](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html)), as I've found they make my code I lot clearer... but one minor bit's always been a sticking point.

Let's say I'm writing an application that contains a Planet object.  I can put the functions relating to Planets in **planet.py**, but then after an **import planet**, I can no longer use a variable named **planet** to refer to one that I'm handling.

Similarly, if the module had a plural name, I wouldn't be able to use **planets** to refer to a list of Planets.

I could certainly shorten them to something like **p** or **ps**, but that's less descriptive.  I suppose one could argue that **planet** or **planets** isn't actually very descriptive, but I feel it makes the most sense if it's not something very persistent, like just a single Planet I'm grabbing out of a set of several.  And I'd hate to start adding excess junk like **planet_list** or **current_planet**.

What are commonly used ways to avoid these name collisions, that don't add excess words while remaining clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, I think sticking to simple naming convention is a good approach. To avoid collisions you can always rename your import:

```
import planet as planetmodule
```

and then you can refer to it as if you'd refer to your original module:

```
planetmodule.somefunction()
```